# How can I test this JSON route in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I have a URL that I want to test like this:

```
/v1/vacations?country=US&year=2017
```

It returns JSON

How can I retrieve the content and check it has records returned or capture the response code in a Unit Test?

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.3 you can do:

```
$content = $this->get('/v1/vacations?country=US&year=2017')->response->getContent();
```

Comment: Do I need to include libraries or something to make this work?
It just errors when executing phpunit?

Comment: I tested it with a clean installation of Laravel version 5.3.31 and it worked for me.

Comment: My test example call is: /my_folder_project/vendor/bin/phpunit /my_folder_project/tests/ResponseTest.php